# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException on XMLDecoder.readObject()

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, xml-serialization, indexoutofboundsexception

There are scenarios in my program where i will be getting the empty object from the properties file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <java version="1.4.1" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
 <object class="java.util.Map">
</object>
</java>
```

On reading the empty object in below code

```
public Object translateObj(
        String data,
        PropertyDefinition propDef) {
        try {
            XMLDecoder decoder =
                new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

            Object object = decoder.readObject();

            decoder.close();

            return object;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("XmlNativeTranslator.translateFromStorage: " +
                " Unable to UTF-8 encode inputData " + data.toString());
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
            s.append("Failed to translate property definition key [");
            s.append(propDef.getKey());
            s.append("] XML contents [");
            s.append(data.toString());
            s.append("]");
            throw new RuntimeException(s.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

On trying to read the empty object in the above code in line decoder.readObject() i am facing the below error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: XmlNativeTranslator.translateFromStorage:
>   Failed to translate property definition key [FORMS_KEY] XML
>   contents [           ] Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

**Need a way to handle this scenario**

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Map` is an interface and you should never encounter it in a serialized form, as it is impossible to have direct instances of an interface.

Valid expressions of empty maps would be, e.g.

```
<object class="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

or

```
<object class="java.util.Collections" method="emptyMap"/>
```

or

```
<object class="java.util.Properties"/>
```

The `XMLDecoder` has the questionable feature of proceeding in the exceptional case, which causes the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as follow-up error.

You can force it to throw the actual exception instead:

```
XMLDecoder dec = new XMLDecoder(new InputSource(new StringReader(data)));
dec.setExceptionListener(ex -> {
    throw ex instanceof RuntimeException? (RuntimeException)ex:
        new RuntimeException("Failed to translate property definition key"+
            " ["+propDef.getKey()+"] XML contents ["+data+"]", ex);
});
Object object = dec.readObject();
return object;
```

Note that by using a `StringReader` there are no encoding errors to handle. I also removed the `close()` step as a `StringReader` has no attached resources and `XMLDecoder.close()` causes even more follow-up errors in the exceptional case when we use try-with-resource.

Using a `StringBuffer` manually is no improvement over string concatenation here; before Java 5 ,the compiler would generate almost identical code, since Java 5 it generates similar code using `StringBuilder` which is even more efficient, not to speak of Java 9 and newer which are even better.

Running this code with your sample input produces

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to translate property definition key [] XML contents [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <java version="1.4.1" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder"> 
 <object class="java.util.Map">
</object>
</java>]
    at ListFiltersToGetMatchingRecords.lambda$main$0(ListFiltersToGetMatchingRecords.java:35)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.handleException(DocumentHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.NewElementHandler.getValueObject(NewElementHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.ElementHandler.endElement(ElementHandler.java:169)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.endElement(DocumentHandler.java:318)
… shortened …
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.DocumentHandler.parse(DocumentHandler.java:372)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(XMLDecoder.java:201)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder$1.run(XMLDecoder.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder.parsingComplete(XMLDecoder.java:199)
    at java.beans.XMLDecoder.readObject(XMLDecoder.java:250)
    at ListFiltersToGetMatchingRecords.main(ListFiltersToGetMatchingRecords.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.Map
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
… shortened …
    at java.beans.Statement.invoke(Statement.java:182)
    at java.beans.Expression.getValue(Expression.java:155)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.ObjectElementHandler.getValueObject(ObjectElementHandler.java:166)
    at com.sun.beans.decoder.NewElementHandler.getValueObject(NewElementHandler.java:123)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.Map.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 42 more
```